# Query to fetch a specific object from a whole json object in MYsql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, database

I have one complex json object field named appjson in my database record

```
{
"id":"123",
"appDetails" : "",
"official" : {
    "comments" : {
        "internalcomments" : "successfull",
        "supportingDocs" : [{}
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Iam able to fetch the whole JSON using straight forward query.

But I dont want the whole comeplex json,I just need specific object from that i.e official

For the whole official object I tried below query and its not working

```
SELECT appjson.official from appdata WHERE id = '123'
```

similarly for just internalcomments I used below

```
SELECT appjson.official.internalcomments from appdata WHERE id = '123'
```

But Iwas unable to fetch that..SO is there any other option/way to fetch specific object from json in MYSQL.

Any help is much appreciated.Thanks

I tried using JSON_EXTRACT

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(appjson, '$."official"') from appdata WHERE id = '123'

But no luck
it is giving JSON_EXTRACT is not recognized built-in function name

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it patently lacks any research effort.

Comment: SQL Error [4104] [S1000]: The multi-part identifier "appjson.official" could not be bound.
 
          The cursor was not declared.
          The executeQuery method must return a result set.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

Comment: @user7350714:  I have updated the answer below check out, it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the step to step to get your desired output.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (id int, jdoc JSON);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)

uery OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)

mysql> insert into t1 values(1,'{
    '> "id":"123",
    '> "appDetails" : "",
    '> "official" : {
    '>     "comments" : {
    '>         "internalcomments" : "successfull",
    '>         "supportingDocs" : [{}
    '>         ]
    '>     }
    '> }
    '> }');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, '$.official') as official from t1 where JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, '$.id') = '123';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| official                                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"comments": {"supportingDocs": [{}], "internalcomments": "successfull"}} |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```